# html form select state and city

Tags: html, css

I am not sure if this question is in the right place so my apologies if it's not. I am using a drop down form to select a state which when clicked goes to a state page. However, I would like to be able to adjust the form so that when a state is clicked a box next to it loads cities within that state. When a city is clicked it then goes to the correct page. Not sure how to do this, the state inline form I am using at the moment is below:

```
<div align="center">
  <form>
    <select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select State Name</option>
      <option value=" state link page</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: `<option value=" state link page" >State Name</option>`!!!

Comment: If you're open to using new technologies, you can do this very quickly and easily with any number of Javascript libraries (particularly Angular.js)

Comment: You can use AJAX to do this.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

Using JavaScript to get cities from an array, linked to states on a select list

Example:

[image: Select a state]

1) Select the state California, and a new drop down list will appear, and you will be told `Selected State: California`

[image: Select a city]

2) If you select the city `Los Angeles`, you are directed to: `cites/los_angeles.html`

*Code:* The code should be quite easy to replicate, but if you would like me to explain to you how to add in more cities/states, I can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
.center{
    margin: auto;
    width: 425px;
}
.selector{
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 425px;
    margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;   
    text-align: center;
}
.heading{
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F00;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function stateSelected(){ 
    var s = document.getElementById("stateSelect");
    var californiaCities = new Array("Los Angeles", "San Francisco");
    var texasCities = new Array("Houston", "Dallas");
        var title = document.createElement("p");
        title.innerHTML = "Select a city:"
        title.className = "heading";
        document.body.appendChild(title);
        switch(s.options[s.selectedIndex].value){
            case "stateCalifornia":
                createSelector(californiaCities, s);
                break;
            case "stateTexas":
                createSelector(texasCities, s);
                break;
        }
}
function createSelector(array, s){
    var sState = document.createElement("p");
    sState.innerHTML = "Selected State: " + s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
    document.body.appendChild(sState);
    var sTitle = document.getElementById("sTitle");
    sTitle.parentNode.removeChild(sTitle);
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
    var newSelect = document.createElement("select");
    var holder = document.createElement("div");
    holder.className = "center";
    var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
    selectOption.selected = "selected";
    selectOption.value = "";
    selectOption.text = "Select a city";
    newSelect.appendChild(selectOption);
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = "city" + array[i].replace(/\s+/g, '');
            newOption.text = array[i];
            newSelect.onchange = townSelected;
            newSelect.id = "citySelect";
            newSelect.appendChild(newOption);
    }
    newSelect.className = "selector";
    holder.appendChild(newSelect);
    document.body.appendChild(holder);
}
function townSelected(){
    var c = document.getElementById("citySelect");
    window.location.href = "cities/" + c.options[c.selectedIndex].text.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase() + ".html";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Made a mistake? <a href="#" onclick="location.reload()">Start Again</a>
</br>
<p id="sTitle" class="heading">Select a state:</p>
<div class="center">
<select id="stateSelect" onchange="stateSelected();" class="selector">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a state</option>
<option value="stateCalifornia">California</option>
<option value="stateTexas">Texas</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add more cities:

In the arrays, for example `californiaCities`, it says `var californiaCities = new Array("Los Angeles", "San Francisco");`. To add another city, simply change the array to `var californiaCities = new Array("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Diego");`, and the `createSelector()` function will do it all for you

How to add more states (slightly more complicated):

In the select box `selectState`, add another option, trying to stick with the same format (stateStateName):

```
<option value="stateNewYork">New York</option>
```

Then, create an array like there is for `californiaCities`:

```
var newYorkCities = new Array("New York City", "Albany");
```

Then, in the switch statement underneath, add the following under the previous `break;` statement:

```
case "stateNewYork":
     createSelector(newYorkCities, s);
     break;
```

Summary: So now, you would have something like:

(HTML) *State selector:*

```
<select id="stateSelect" onchange="stateSelected();" class="selector">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a state</option>
<option value="stateCalifornia">California</option>
<option value="stateTexas">Texas</option>
<option value="stateNewYork">New York</option>
</select>
```

(JavaScript) *Array declarations:*

```
var californiaCities = new Array("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Diego");
var texasCities = new Array("Houston", "Dallas");
var newYorkCities = new Array("New York City", "Albany");
```

(JavaScript) *Switch statement:*

```
switch(s.options[s.selectedIndex].value){
        case "stateCalifornia":
            createSelector(californiaCities, s);
            break;
        case "stateTexas":
            createSelector(texasCities, s);
            break;
        case "stateNewYork":
            createSelector(newYorkCities, s);
            break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Basically I already have in place what you mentioned above. For example, when someone clicks California it already goes to the page for California. What I was hoping to do was have 2 boxes, one with state as above and when the state is selected a box under this populates with cities (that have static pages) that I have configured. When clicking on the second option (city) the user would be taken to that page. Hope that clarifies it?

Comment: To summarise: Click on State, then click on City (where the city has a html link in it). Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @user1062938 - New answer

Comment: Thanks looks absolutely perfect for me needs so thanks so much for taking the time to show me this. If you could let me know how to add in more states and cities (cities will be added as and when they have content) including their links that would be great. Thanks again, saved me alot of time.

Comment: Hello,Just tested this but I only get one box when using the code above (the state select box). I don't see a city select. Sorry, my coding knowledge is crap so it is probably something I am doing wrong. I copied the code above and pasted it into the page. When I view the page I get state select only. Thanks again, Andrew

Comment: @user1062938 - When you click on the state inside the state select box, it disappears, and then you get the city box. As for adding more states, I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks Joe, Will test it out! Really appreciate your time and patience!:-) Andrew

Comment: Hello, I have been testing this out in a sidebar widget in Wordpress. The state select works really well however, when I select a state the select city box moves to the center of the page instead of coming up where the state box was. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1062938 - Perhaps post a question with the `wordpress` tag, and see what happens: I'm not very familiar with Wordpress at all. Sorry if this is not what you wanted

Comment: Thanks Joe, no need to apologise, it really helped. Just need to tweak it!:-)

Comment: @user1062938 - By clicking the tick next to my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<div align="center">
  <form>
    <select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select State Name</option>
      <option value="state link page">State Name</option>
      <option value="state link page">State Name</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

on state page

```
<div align="center">
  <form>
    <select name="cities" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select State Name</option>
      <option value="City link page">City Name</option>
      <option value="City link page">City Name</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using an IFrame. This could be done much better using AJAX if you were willing to use a library such as JQuery, where you coulse use `.load` on a DIV instead. But without JQuery you could do:

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <form>
        <select id="selectBox" name="URL">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Select State Name</option>
            <option value="florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="texas">Texas</option>
        </select>
        <iframe id="statePage"></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
selectionChange = function() {
    var elStatePage = document.getElementById('statePage'); 
    elStatePage.src = 'states/' + this.value + '.htm';
}

var e = document.getElementById('selectBox'); 
e.onchange = selectionChange;
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zXz8s/

Comment: Wow - that's a lot of advise in such a short period! Thanks very much. I am not much use when it comes to coding. This is on a wordpress website where I want to make navigation easier. The particular theme I am using doesn't work well with long menus which is why I wanted a selection drop down from the main page which when selected takes the viewer to a hard coded page. I will give the above suggestions a try - if there is an easier way then please let me know. Thanks again!